# How to increase the range of an array taken from an API query

Tags: react-native, api, use-state

I have a function for when clicking a button increase the contents of a list.

Content is removed from an API by the following code:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState();
const [maxRange, setMaxRange] = useState(2);


const getAPIinfo = ()=>{
      GetEvents(maxRange, 0).then((response) => response.json())
      .then(result_events => {
        const events = result_events;
        setData({events:events});
      }).catch(e => setData({events:events}));      
    }
```

And my function is this:

```js
const buttonLoadMore = ({data,type}) =>{
      setMaxRange(prevRange => prevRange + 4);
      data = data.slice(0,maxRange);
    }
```

**what I'm not able to do is update the maxRange value of the API query to increase the list...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this function should be heavily refactored:

```
const buttonLoadMore = ({data,type}) =>{
  setMaxRange(prevRange => prevRange + 4);
  data = data.slice(0,maxRange);
}
```

when you use maxRange here, you are setting new state, while the function itself ir running, the state is not instantly updated, `buttonLoadMore` is a function in a particular time. it cannot get new maxRange instantly, while running `buttonLoadMore` does that make sense? Also you cannot update `data` state just like a regular variable by assigning new variable using `=` operator, you should refactor this function to something like this:

```
const buttonLoadMore = ({data})=> {
  const newMaxRange = maxRange + 4;
  setMaxRange(newMaxRange);

  const newData = {events: [...data.events.slice(0, newMaxRange)]};
  setData({...newData})
}
```

also you will get bug here. since your `getAPIinfo` is setting `data` state to an object `{events: events}`. I took the liberty and tried refactoring it here.

There is also a bug in your `getAPIinfo` in line `}).catch(e => setData({events:events}));` the `events` variable you declared in `.then` function cannot be reached here. It is simply out of scope. unless you know that .catch resolves into data, you will get an error in this line.

take a look at this example here:

```
const promiseFunction = ()=>{
  return new Promise<string>((resolve)=>resolve('i like coca cola'))
}

const getter = () => {
  promiseFunction()
    .then(response => {
      const thenVariable = response;
      console.log(thenVariable) // i like coca cola
    })
  .catch(error=>{
    console.log(thenVariable) // Error:Cannot find name 'thenVariable'.
  })
}
```

as you can see `.catch()` is in different *scope* than `.then()` will not be available outside so `events` cannot be reached by `.catch` function.

Usually you would use catch for error handling. Maybe show a line on screen, that error has accoured, and data cannot be fetched at this time. etc. There's a very good book that explains all these concepts in detail here: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS

I would strongly recommend for you to switch to typescript because your code is crawling with bugs that should be easily avoided just by type checking, and adding eslint configurations.